# Python Docker Image: _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: python, windows, docker, containers

```
Host Machine: Windows 10 Enterprise

Application: Docker Desktop for Windows

Container option: Linux Containers
```

I have a python script basically a countdown timer. The code can be found from the website https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-countdown-timer-using-python-tkinter/
I named this source file as timer.py and able to run it using python.exe

I am trying to containerize the same using docker.
I have pulled in Python3.6 image from the docker hub. My docker file is as below.

```
FROM python

COPY . /opt/

WORKDIR /opt

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "timer.py"]
```

I built the image and when I run the container I get hte following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timer.py", line 7, in <module>
    root = Tk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2261, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I don't understand the error, I have searched through StackOverflow with similar error couldn't find a solution for my problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

note: 1. I am able to containerize and run a simple python script with just a print("hello world"), but with Tkinter I am not able to
2. For some reason not able to pull in images using the windows containers option, so trying in Linux containers.

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/enigmampc/catalyst/issues/39#issuecomment-570282239

Comment: That error message means that the program inside the container can't connect to a Linux-compatible display system.  I'd suggest not using Docker for this kind of interactive graphical application: the setup to make it work is complicated, finicky, and platform-dependent.  Is there a specific reason you think you want Docker here?

Comment: @DavidMaze The current project I am working on needs to Dockerize a Python based software application which has a GUI. So I was trying out a sample script to verify the functionality